# Можна писати "народа" без лапок, посилаючися на джерело після тексту? Чи це все одно помилка?

Tags: вживання-слів

Відмінювання  «народа» можна прочитати у Франка, в листах, щодо перекладу Біблії (http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/75098/13-Doljikova.pdf?sequence=1). В цій роботі, наприклад. Франко - мовний взірець. Але правопис вказує на те, що правильно "для народу". Якщо написати в творі: "Франко писав для народа" та подібні відмінювання,  чи обов'язково брати в лапки? Хочу написати таку цікаву роботу, художню, посилаючись на його стиль та спосіб. В кінці додам, що застосовувала Франкові мовні звички.

Comment: Чесно кажучи, я взагалі не зрозумів, про що це запитання. Ви запитуєте про «`-а` чи `-у`», або про використання лапок, або про стилістику і звички Франка? Намагайтеся точніше пропрацьовувати запитання, щоб заохотити інших відповідати на них.

Comment: Я хочу переписати сучасний текст так, як написав би Франко. Питаю, чи використовувати на кожне слово, яке різниця з правилами, лапки.